# Swift: Trying to set a ui button title using a completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uibutton

I am trying to use data from firebase to populate buttons on the UI. Everything works as expected except the button title is not updating. Any ideas on how to fix this?

@IBAction func addNewTapped(_ sender: Any) {

```
    readOneDay2(lastMonday(trackerDate), completion: { message in
            let lastHourRead = message
            print(message)
            self.lastHour1.setTitle(lastHourRead, for: UIControl.State.application)

    })
}

func readOneDay2 (_ mydate: Date, completion: @escaping (_ message: String) -> Void){
    
    var db: DatabaseReference!
    db = Database.database().reference()
    var totalComb: Double = 0.0
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    db.child("TimesheetData").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        
        for (key, value) in dict! {
            
            let myvalue = value as? [String: Any]
            let compDate: String = myvalue!["timeSheetDate"]! as! String
            if compDate == dateStringer(mydate) {
                let sHours: String = myvalue!["hours"]! as! String
                let sOverTime: String = myvalue!["overTime"]! as! String
                let sDoubleTime: String = myvalue!["doubleTime"]! as! String
                let dHours: Double = Double(sHours)!
                let dOverTime: Double = Double(sOverTime)!
                let dDoubleTime: Double = Double(sDoubleTime)!
                totalComb = totalComb + dHours + dOverTime + dDoubleTime
                print(key)
                
            }
        }
        print("First Sum " + String(totalComb))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(String(totalComb))
        }
      }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: change UIControl.State.application -> UIControl.State.normal

Comment: Hi Virender, that didn't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Virender said,

Change UIControl.State.application to UIControl.State.normal

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.lastHour1.setTitle(lastHourRead, for:.normal)
    }
```

Comment: I made that change but no effect.

Comment: are you sure you are getting log : print(message)?